# New Version of Clustered Travelling Salesman Problem

Tags: math, optimization

I have an instance of a quadratic bounded TSP 
(quadratic: the cost function depends on two edges, not just one -> f(i,j,k)->cost; i,j and k can be interpreted in the context of a path so that i is the node we are coming from, then we are going over j, so j is the current node and then going to k, so k is the next node;
 bounded: a single edge weight must not exceed a certain limit)
 and I'm trying to solve this using Concorde.
To do this, I transform my Problem: Originally, I have a list of points P with length n. Then I define a new point list with each point from P contained n times and the added nodes clustered so that the same points belong to one cluster. Inside the cluster, the different points correspond to coming from different points to the point in the cluster. 
In a cost_matrix, I define the cost vales for every possible triple of points. If it is not possible to traverse a triple, I use infinity as cost.
So the solution, I am looking for is going through each cluster exactly once and has length < infinity. Is Concorde able to do so? ChatGPT said yes, however all its implementations caused Concorde errors because of unexpected arguments.

Comment: Remember that ChatGPT doesn't tell the truth, it's not a code-writing service, it's a _story generation_ service. It can only give plausible-looking answers, and the more complex your problem, the more it'll lie to generate something that sounds plausible. If you get code, it's on _you_ to check the actual API documentation for the language(s) and libraries it claims are necessary, to verify that the code it gave you even makes any sense at all.

Comment: Unfortunately the Concorde library is not very well documented. I have of course checked ChatGPTs answers and looked into the source code of the library and could not find, what ChatGPT used either. This is why I've posted the question, so that I know wether Concorde can do, what ChatGPT said or if it was just made up.

Comment: do your clusters overlap?  meaning if we are traveling (i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p) do you consider (i, j, k), (j, k, l), (l, m, n), (m, n, o), ....  to **all** be clusters, or can you freely travel between clusters of 3?  If the latter, you can probably bin your 3-tuples and then consider them to be the nodes.

Comment: *"This is why I've posted the question, so that I know wether Concorde can do, what ChatGPT said or if it was just made up."* <<< Happy to answer that question. The answer is: ChatGPT made it up. That's what ChatGPT does; that's what is is programmed to do.

Comment: @AirSquid, the Clusters do not overlap. Could you explain you approach a little further and tell me, how I can use Concorde, or some other efficient Solver to solve the Problem? I have programmed an algorithm for the original version of the quadratic bounded TSP, however it is really, really slow and inefficient. This is, why I want to use a more sophisticated Solver